# Interrupted debug at loading symbol yielded to ntdll.pdb missing

Tags: visual-studio, symbols, visual-studio-2022, debug-symbols, missing-symbols

I was launching and stopping debug in visual studio really quick as I was testing something in a DLL entry point and at some point I clicked by error on "cancel" in the loading symbols window. Since then, when I launch debug, I keep having an access violation because of a "ntdll.pdb" missing.

I tried to load the symbols from Microsoft servers, but it takes ages. I would simply like to return everything back to normal, as it was before my miss-click.

Comment: You didn't get the AV because of the missing .pdb file.  It is *very* common for ntdll.dll to report an AV, it is happy to take the blame for an incorrect winapi function call in your program.  Use Debug > Windows > Call Stack to find out how it got there, you'll find the location of the bad call in the list.  Double-click it to open the source file for it.

Comment: @HansPassant I had no AV before the miss-click, code was executing fine. Isn't it possible, without further investigation, to get back to the pre-miss-click state somehow ?

Comment: @HansPassant I erased the whole solution folder, cloned it at the same place, had the same problem. I then cloned it elsewhere and ... did not have the problem. I must admit that it satisfies me for now, but still, I'd like to know how to make VS search and load symbols from where it does it initially, before any miss-click or modification.